# TCP SACK Overlapping Options

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm facing a strange issue. We have two systems communicating via RFC, but this communication breaks everytime with the following issue:

The Client receives an TCP ACK with an SLE=2734286 and SLR=2777173
Client then starts a retransmission of the "missing" packages
Then receives a TCP DUP ACK with SACK: 2777089-2777173 2734286-2777173

This is weird, isnt it? The SACK parameters are overlapping. The Client then sends again the missing packages but always receives the TCP DUP ACK. After 5 tries the client gives up.

Its Windows 2003 to Linux 2.6.32.

Is someone of you aware of such an issue? The Network connection itself is working without issues (for ex. when copying data via SSH, there the SACK protocol seems to work correct).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with those SACKs according to the RFC (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2018). The data receiver is **supposed** to trim the second SACK, but it's not a firm requirement (from Section 4):

> The SACK option SHOULD be filled out by repeating the most recently
>   reported SACK blocks based  on first SACK blocks in previous SACK
>   options) that are not subsets of a SACK block already included in the
>   SACK option being constructed

I suspect the data receiver's implementation (this is the server in your example) consists of just generating a SACK entry whenever a segment arrives and pushing it into a list, without trying to collapse the list every time.